# ¿Cómo hacer la extracción de varias lineas de texto HTML (no consecutivas) en SQL Server?

Tags: sql

Espero puedan ayudarme con esta consulta, tengo que extraer varias cadenas de texto a la vez de un código HTML, pude hacer el filtro de la primera de esas cadenas con SUBSTRING Y CHARINDEX, las demás cadenas inician con el mismo texto por lo que debería poder extraerlas con un ciclo While, pero no se me ocurre cómo, lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
DECLARE @Cadena VARCHAR(MAX)='<p class="variations-title">
                    <span>Color:</span>
                    <strong data-js="variations-title">
                        118 - Dancer
                    </strong>
                </p>

<ul class="  vip-variation-list variation-list">

    <li data-value="MTA1IC0gRXhwbG9yZXI=" data-type="image" data-title="105 - Explorer" data-status="enable" class=" 
        ui-list__item

        ">

        <div class="ui-tooltip ui-tooltip--bottom-center">
            <a class="ui-list__item-option" href="https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/noindex/variation/choose?noIndex=true&amp;itemId=MLA809213191&amp;attribute=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR%7CMTA1IC0gRXhwbG9yZXI%3D&amp;attributeId=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR&amp;backFromPickerMobile=false">

<figure class="vip-variation-image">
    <img src="https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_785236-MLA31846349356_082019-S.webp" data-src-original="https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_785236-MLA31846349356_082019-F.webp" alt="105 - Explorer">
</figure>

            </a>

                <div class="ui-tooltip__data">
                    <p class="ui-tooltip__title">Sin stock</p>
                </div>

        </div>
    </li>


    <li data-value="MTEwIC0gT3JpZ2luYXRvcg==" data-type="image" data-title="110 - Originator" data-status="enable" class=" 
        ui-list__item

        ">

        <div class="ui-tooltip ui-tooltip--bottom-center">
            <a class="ui-list__item-option" href="https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/noindex/variation/choose?noIndex=true&amp;itemId=MLA809213191&amp;attribute=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR%7CMTEwIC0gT3JpZ2luYXRvcg%3D%3D&amp;attributeId=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR&amp;backFromPickerMobile=false">

<figure class="vip-variation-image">
    <img src="https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_730536-MLA31846349365_082019-S.webp" data-src-original="https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_730536-MLA31846349365_082019-F.webp" alt="110 - Originator">
</figure>


            </a>

                <div class="ui-tooltip__data">
                    <p class="ui-tooltip__title">Sin stock</p>
                </div>

        </div>
    </li>


    <li data-value="MTE1IC0gRm91bmRlcg==" data-type="image" data-title="115 - Founder" data-status="enable" class=" 
        ui-list__item

        ">

        <div class="ui-tooltip ui-tooltip--bottom-center">
            <a class="ui-list__item-option" href="https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/noindex/variation/choose?noIndex=true&amp;itemId=MLA809213191&amp;attribute=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR%7CMTE1IC0gRm91bmRlcg%3D%3D&amp;attributeId=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR&amp;backFromPickerMobile=false">

<figure class="vip-variation-image">
    <img src="https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_670302-MLA31846349367_082019-S.webp" data-src-original="https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_670302-MLA31846349367_082019-F.webp" alt="115 - Founder">
</figure>

            </a>

                <div class="ui-tooltip__data">
                    <p class="ui-tooltip__title">Sin stock</p>
                </div>

        </div>
    </li>

    <li data-value="MTE4IC0gRGFuY2Vy" data-type="image" data-title="118 - Dancer" data-status="selected" class=" variations-selected
        ui-list__item

        ">

        <div class="ui-tooltip ui-tooltip--bottom-center">
            <a class="ui-list__item-option" href="https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/noindex/variation/choose?noIndex=true&amp;itemId=MLA809213191&amp;attribute=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR%7CMTE4IC0gRGFuY2Vy&amp;attributeId=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR&amp;backFromPickerMobile=false">

<figure class="vip-variation-image">
    <img src="https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_725010-MLA31846349373_082019-S.webp" data-src-original="https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_725010-MLA31846349373_082019-F.webp" alt="118 - Dancer">
</figure>
            </a>

                <div class="ui-tooltip__data">
                    <p class="ui-tooltip__title">Sin stock</p>
                </div>

        </div>
    </li>

    <li data-value="MTIwIC0gQXJ0aXN0" data-type="image" data-title="120 - Artist" data-status="enable" class=" 
        ui-list__item

        ">

        <div class="ui-tooltip ui-tooltip--bottom-center">
            <a class="ui-list__item-option" href="https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/noindex/variation/choose?noIndex=true&amp;itemId=MLA809213191&amp;attribute=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR%7CMTIwIC0gQXJ0aXN0&amp;attributeId=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR&amp;backFromPickerMobile=false">

<figure class="vip-variation-image">
    <img src="https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_764958-MLA31846349368_082019-S.webp" data-src-original="https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_764958-MLA31846349368_082019-F.webp" alt="120 - Artist">
</figure>


            </a>

                <div class="ui-tooltip__data">
                    <p class="ui-tooltip__title">Sin stock</p>
                </div>

        </div>
    </li>

    <li data-value="MTI1IC0gSW5zcGlyZXI=" data-type="image" data-title="125 - Inspirer" data-status="enable" class=" 
        ui-list__item

        ">

        <div class="ui-tooltip ui-tooltip--bottom-center">
            <a class="ui-list__item-option" href="https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/noindex/variation/choose?noIndex=true&amp;itemId=MLA809213191&amp;attribute=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR%7CMTI1IC0gSW5zcGlyZXI%3D&amp;attributeId=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR&amp;backFromPickerMobile=false">

<figure class="vip-variation-image">
    <img src="https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_915244-MLA31846349341_082019-S.webp" data-src-original="https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_915244-MLA31846349341_082019-F.webp" alt="125 - Inspirer">
</figure>

            </a>
                <div class="ui-tooltip__data">
                    <p class="ui-tooltip__title">Sin stock</p>
                </div>

        </div>
    </li>
```

'

SELECT @Cadena = SUBSTRING(@Cadena,CHARINDEX('data-title="',@Cadena) + LEN('data-title="'),LEN(@Cadena))
SELECT @Cadena = SUBSTRING(@Cadena,1,CHARINDEX('"',@Cadena) - 1)
SELECT @Cadena

RESULTADO:
105 - Explorer

Los resultados que me faltan son:
 110 - Originator,
 115 - Founder,
 118 - Dancer,
 120 - Artist,
 125 - Inspirer
 (TODOS INICIAN CON 'data-title="')

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción eficiente, puede ser mediante el uso de funciones XML. Claro está, que tienes que convertir tu cadena en un formato XML válido.

```
DECLARE @xCadena XML = REPLACE( @Cadena,'</figure>', '</img></figure>') + '</ul>';

SELECT r.li.value('./@data-title', 'varchar(100)') AS [data-title]
FROM @xCadena.nodes('/ul/li') AS r(li);
```